# PHP - returning method value to a variable not working

Tags: php, email, variables, methods, return

Ok, so i am building an html email from the values given from a contact form on a page.  THe way the code is set up, you submit the contact form and the the backend takes all of the submitted values, turns them into an array and then ships them off to a method that builds the html email.  That method returns all of the html for the email and we then stick that in a `$message` variable to use with the PHP mailer.

I've done some logging on the system to try and figure out what the issue is but have been unsuccessful.  If i log the output of the method that builds the html email it does correctly return the html.  However, the returned value is somehow not being set in the variable.  Here's what i mean:

Variable to be set by returned value from method:

```
$message = Email::returnView('email/formSubmission', $emailData);
```

Code inside the method:

```
public static function returnView($view, $data=null)
{
    $viewloc = BASE_PATH . "views/{$view}.view";
    if (file_exists($viewloc)) {
        ob_start();
        require($viewloc);
        flushblocks();
        return ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        throw new Exception("View not found: {$view}.view");
    }
}
```

Logging the output of `ob_get_clean()` gives the correct data so it is being returned correctly.  Even when i log `Email::returnView('email/formSubmission', $emailData)` i get the correct html data.  This is the data that the method returns:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Submission</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
    <p>
        Name: Full Name<br/>
        phone: 555-555-5555<br/>
        email: test@example.com<br/>
        comments: test<br/>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

BUT, when i try and log `$message` it is empty.  Is it not working because the html may not be a string?

Comment: What do you get if you do print_r(Email::returnView('email/formSubmission', $emailData)); ? If you get the HTML content, then the issue is somehwere else and we would need more code to help.

Comment: @Scalpweb, print_r looks like it gives the correct output.

Comment: So can you please provide the full script aounrd $message = Email::returnView('email/formSubmission', $emailData); ? What do you get if you do print_r($message) just after that line ?

Comment: What's inside flushblocks? would it flush the buffer internally ?

Comment: This is how i am logging to the console.

`$message = Email::returnView('email/formSubmission', $emailData);
\Framework\Helper_Log::log(Email::returnView('email/formSubmission', $emailData));
\Framework\Helper_Log::log($message);`

First log gives me the correct data, second is empty.

Comment: Ok, does this make sense to anyone given that the method is just returning `ob_get_clean()`?  If i use `$message = Email::returnView('email/formSubmission', (object)$emailData);` It is empty.  But if i comment out the return inside the method and then use `$message = ob_get_clean();` and call `Email::sendEmail($to, $from, $subject, $message);` it works!  What's the difference with returning the value to a variable and actually outputting to the variable itself?

Comment: After further investigation, @DavidLin was on the right path.  I commented out `flushblocks()` and everything is working.  I guess it is flushing it before `return ob_get_clean()` can get it.  This code was not mine so now i need to figure out why it was written that way / what `flushblocks()` is doing.